# WP_User_Query and Custom User Tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a new Wordpress site that is using custom shared user tables to access user data from an existing Wordpress site on the same server.

Whenever I try to use `WP_User_Query();` it returns no results, even without any arguments.

Is there a way to use `WP_User_Query` with the custom shared tables? I am having to use a custom query but I would much rather use the built in Wordpress functions.

Comment: Have you tried updating the users (table) property of wpdb?

Comment: @NathanDawson I didn't know I could do that. What would that look like?

Comment: I'll submit an answer but I'm coding on the fly so I can't be sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your wpdb object's user (table) property. This tells it which table to lookup the users in. You can do this by setting the CUSTOM_USER_TABLE constant.

Add the following to your functions.php file:

```
if ( ! defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) ) { 
    define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'custom-users-table-name' );
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I already have this line of code in wp-config.php:`define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'my-custom-users-table');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'my-custom-usermeta-table');`

Comment: I'm correct in assuming you're giving me that as an example and have actually used the real table names on your site?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am able to use the following query to return the users: `SELECT $wpdb->users.ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name ASC`

Comment: Is this on a multisite?

Comment: No I have been looking into using multisite but it doesn't seem to be geared towards what I'm trying to do here. (It doesn't sound like it would be worth the hassle to set up if sharing posts across sites is not something that multisite was meant to do - especially because this isn't two completely brand new sites: I would have to integrate an existing site that's already on a subdomain and has years worth of data in it and is also a password protected "members only" type site into the mu network.)

Comment: Sorry, I realized that you aren't aware of my situation so you might be confused by that previous comment. My client has requested that their new company website (www.company.com) retrieves posts and user meta from their existing "employees only" website (intranet.company.com). So because WPMU seems to be geared towards having multiple sites that do not share posts, it didn't seem like the right solution, especially because I would have to migrate an existing site into the network which is likely to end up causing myriad additional headaches.

Comment: @kisabelle - No worries. I'm afraid I'd need considerably more information to solve this particular problem so I won't be able to help through here. I'm sure someone else will come along with the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am able to accomplish what I set out to do without using `WP_User_Query();` I just wanted to ask around to make sure I wasn't missing some simple step that could get it to work!